# Создать таблицу/массив из данных json в swift 4

Tags: json, swift, парсер

Есть код:

```
let adress = "http://MyServ/WEB2/odata/standard.odata/Catalog_Klient?$format=json"
        guard let url = URL(string: adress) else {return}
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
           if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            guard let data = data else { return}
            print(data)
            do {
                let jsonStr = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(jsonStr)
            } catch{
                print(error)
            }
            }.resume()
```

Имеем такой ответ JSON, т.е. моя константа "jsonStr":

```
{
"odata.metadata": "http://MyServ/WEB2/odata/standard.odata/$metadata#Catalog_Klient",
"value": [{
"Ref_Key": "c9ca0efd-39a9-11e9-9422-0cc47a448b68",
"DataVersion": "AAAAAQAAAAA=",
"DeletionMark": false,
"Code": "000000001",
"Description": "TEST",
"Predefined": false,
"PredefinedDataName": ""
},{
"Ref_Key": "1413903c-39aa-11e9-9422-0cc47a448b68",
"DataVersion": "AAAAAgAAAAA=",
"DeletionMark": false,
"Code": "000000002",
"Description": "TEST2",
"Predefined": false,
"PredefinedDataName": ""
}]}
```

Как получить таблицу или массив вида:

> 1) 000000001 | TEST  |
>
> 2) 000000002 | TEST2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы распарсить JSON из полученных данных, создадим структуры:

- ResponseItem - будет хранить элементы массива:

```swift
struct ResponseItem {
    var code: String
    var description: String
}
```

- Response - будет хранить весь ответ сервера:

```swift
struct Response {
    var value: [ResponseItem]
}
```

Эти структуры должны реализовать протокол `Decodable`. С `Response` всё просто, так как ответ содержит `value` с маленькой буквы:

```swift
extension Response: Decodable {}
```

С `ResponseItem` чуть посложнее, так как ответ сервера содержит ключи с большой буквы, а в Swift принято называть переменные с маленькой буквы. Необходимо сказать компилятору, какое значение в какую переменную записывать при парсинге:

```swift
extension ResponseItem: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code = "Code"
        case description = "Description"
    }
}
```

Теперь используем созданне структуры и распарсим ответ с помощью `JSONDecoder`:

```swift
let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
```

Для проверки можно вывести результат в консоль:

```swift
print(decoded)
```